# How to add a removable asset to an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to ship a custom file with an iOS app, but I also need an option to delete it later not to use any extra space on the device.

**Failed attempts:**

1. I've tried to add the file to `Assets.xcassets` which works like a charm but, as I understand, assets cannot be deleted.
2. I've also tried to write this file to the documents directory from the assets, so that I could later delete it via `FileManager.default.removeItem(at: ...)`. However, I still need to access the assets for that.
3. Some other notion would probably be to use *Resources*, but I don't see how I can add a file to the resources and still be able to delete it later programmatically.

Comment: You can’t modify the app bundle. If you ship it with the app it stays in the app.

Comment: Read about "On Demand Resources" . It might help... https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html

Comment: @EmilioPelaez what if we don't use assets but use Resources? We still can't delete them, right?

Comment: @WarrenBurton the problem is that I need this resource right away (right after the app start)

Comment: Right, it doesn't matter how you add it, if it's included in app bundle it can't be modified. That said, images in xcassets are optimized, and in theory the AppStore should only distribute the relevant resolutions for each device. Unless you're using dozens of high quality images, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @mathjunkie is this an actual issue for your customers right now? Not trying to be mean, but is this premature optimisation.  Unless you’re bundling 100MB+ of once only data  then probably not worth worrying about IMO.